# pywinauto to control putty.exe

Tags: python, pywinauto

How can I see the result of the 'msfconsole' command?

```
app_Putty = Application().Start(cmd_line='putty -ssh user@10.10.10.10 ')
app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys("password {ENTER}")
time.sleep(5)
command = 'msfconsole'
app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys(command+"{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Ah, again... One more guy who doesn’t know about SSH and Paramiko.

Comment: I'm know with paramiko , but can you see the result of the metasploit commands in paramiko?
    stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('msfconsole')